# Glide: Unable to Build AppGlideModule (compileSdkVersion 28)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

I am attempting to implement the [AppGlideModule](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html) for Glide.

**Error**

`GeneratedAppGlideModule with: []`

**Steps Taken To Resolve**

- Cleaned build
- Rebuilt app
- Invalide Caches / Restart for Android Studio
- Exclude `com.android.support` from Glide since I'm using sdk version 28.
- Using  `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt` which compiles and runs the app, however `GlideApp` still cannot be accessed. The AppGlideModule is in the same package where I am attempting to use the GlideApp object.

**Configuration**

- Language: Kotlin *1.2.51*
- compileSdkVersion: 28

**Implementation**

*build.gradle(Project: carpecoin)*

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha04"
}
```

*build.gradle(Module: app)*

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'`
//I've tried with and without this line for annotations implementation.
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'
```

`kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'`

*MyAppGlideModule*

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

**All External Libraries Used**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2:$paging_version"

implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx fo
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
```

Comment: Did you apply `kotlin-kapt` plugin?

Comment: Good point. I did include that. I just updated my notes above to show that.

Comment: the cause is `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01`, it will be working if you use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jaychang0917. I implemented the non "androidx" `appcompat` with `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'` and `kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'` separately. 

The `annotationProcessor` method did not generate the `GlideApp` object. The `kapt` method does not compile with the same error message indicated in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

The **GlideApp** is successfully being generated after upgrading Glide's library to **4.8.0**. **kapt** is being used since the app is built using Kotlin.

*build.gradle* (Module: app)

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```